# Can I use a large capacitor to boost the current of a circuit for a short period?

Tags: arduino, supercapacitor

I'm working on an RPi-Pico (Adafruit Feather RP2040) project that runs off of computer USB power (5V/500mA-1A).

I need to simultaneously move 3 motors that run at 6V-8V/250mA, but only for approximately 1 second.

So far I've put together a [Falstad circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEBmAHAJmgdgGzoRmACzICcpkORKWISJdApgLRhgBQAbuDiOqqh49IUUURFIRU6AnYBjcKXTDFy-oIkgi2VJATJI6SEQIUi1beXYAnEFT4C71MDinhI7AO6qV6lR4BzJwdBewNqKS9wfhV7F0jbMBi-MCUQ0RgOWz8cx3jRTHR2MARSH3ykwQqoWEgII3hGuCjcqrS-DwAPEGYcZD5IKr42LWiQACUABQBLAB0AZxm5AHsFhAA1dm7kMBEjQWQsepHnZQBZZYAXZesFgBllgEMAEy2QUiQwZGp0NHBD0ZJEAAEWmAWml0eABsoQBPZgAYWWADtLtZljDGM8FgBlTwQuQACyilXS9g6UXJeV4FO8LlizlcUHYy3AwRE4nIdBqjVIuAQeEkfDZyHYQA) that almost does what I want it to do. I haven't added any boost converters to go up to the 6V-8V/250mA, but (as far as I know) the watts are high enough when the switch is open.

The problem I'm having is the microcontroller I'm using can only output 5V/500mA max, and I can't get the circuit tuned where the Pico is only outputting 500mA. Currently it steady-states at about 2.7A.

**Ultimately what I'm trying to do:**

**Switch Open:**

- 5V/500mA through the RPi
- 6V-8V/250mA for 1 second through the motor load

**Switch Closed:**

- 5V/250mA through the RPi

[image: falstad circuit]

Comment: I assume you're powering the Raspberry Pi via USB?  If you're not married to USB power for some reason it may work better to use a supply that's powerful enough for the motors, power the Pi off of that, and control the motors with the Pi.

Comment: @TimWescott unfortunately the goal is for it to be a computer accessory, so I am married to computer USB power

Comment: usb won't give you more than 500ma if you also use it for communication. If you don't use it for communication, then use a generic usb socket instead of the built-in one, giving you a raw 5v, which you can feed into a pin to power the pico and drive the motors aside the pi.

Comment: @TimWescott I do intend to also be using communication through USB. I'm also limited to 500mA by the pi itself, it has a maximum, momentary output of 500mA. As far as I can tell, I won't be able to escape the 5V/500mA without using another power source (which ideally I wouldn't do)

Comment: "Currently it steady states at about 2.7A".  This contradicts three motors at 250mA (which should add up to 750mA).  I think you need to _edit your question_ with more detail.  Do you mean that your motors consume 2.7A _forever_, or for one second, or what?  Why does it consume almost four times more than your motor current figure suggests?  If you can't answer that directly, you may want to include a schematic of how you're driving your motors, and perhaps even comment on what the motors are driving (because that affects the current they'll pull).

Answer (score 0):

A 6V cap loaded by 250 mA is equivalent to 24 ohms might have a coil Rs of 2~3 ohms that defines the surge start. A supercap, if added to sustain a 1V/s sag would require Ic=CdV/dt or 250 mF.